# Irritation vs. Anger

Tags: mussar-ethics

I know, according to Torah, its a sin to be angry but is it a sin to be irritated? For example, if a child yells really loud and I calmly tell him to stop yelling, does the fact that I calmly told him to stop yelling make me angry? On the inside I feel irritated because he was yelling really loud but is irritation and anger the same thing?

Comment: Yes they are the same thing just to a lesser degree - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.2.3?ven=Mishnah_Torah,_Yod_ha-hazakah,_trans._by_Simon_Glazer,_1927&lang=bi

Comment: There's a word רתח , usually boil but it's used as getting irritated or angry.. might be useful for you.  Also Istenis, "sensitive person".  Sefer Hamidot section Kaas, Anger. 4. Do not boil up/get hot (RTCh) and you will not sin (ChT').

5. Whoever gets angry, his wisdom and prophetic ability departs. And even if greatness has been decreed for him in Heaven, he is brought down from his greatness.

6. The Holy One Blessed be He loves one who does not become angry and one who does not harbor resentment.

7. A hot-tempered person's life is not worth living.

Comment: See Rambam Hilchos Deos ch. 1.

Comment: Thank you everyone!  